# How to throw the exceptions when reading from the directory?

Tags: scala

When I read from a directory in Scala, what is the proper way to catch the exceptions and how to initialize `directory`?

```
var directory = ??

try {
  directory = new File(path)
}
catch {

}

if (directory.exists) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `Try`:

```
Try(new File("path"))
  .filter(_.exists)
  .map(directory => 
      // do something with the code
  ).recover{
  case exc: Exception =>
    // handle Exception
 }
```

You can also replace the `if` with a `filter`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check my more concrete question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555477/how-to-throw-the-exceptions-in-scala-and-test-them-in-unit-tests

Comment: I prefer to not use the generic `Exception` but specify concrete exceptions with `case`.

Comment: @Markus you can handle whatever Exception you like in recover.